# How Hbase write its data and where

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new in Hbase , I just want  understanding of Hbase write operation.
If multiple clients are writing in same table then how Hbase maintain a sequential write to physical file.

Where Hbase Store its data (I think in HDFS)?

Can we store Hbase data out side HDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Write operation you can refer to this link: http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.writing.html

Comment: Can we store Hbase data out side HDFS?

Answer (score 6):

HBase writes the data to a memstore first and flushes that to disk when it is full or upon request HBase also writes the data to a write-ahead-log (WAL) to prevent dataloss (you can turn that off if you need).

The memstore data is flushed into HFiles which are stored in HDFS. HBase needs HDFS to provide the data availability (via HDFS replication). HBase cannot store data outside of HDFS