# where are hbase namespaces/tables data stored on the hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Where does hbase store data files for namespace/tables?
I've found this post : [How Hbase write its data and where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973189/how-hbase-write-its-data-and-where) but I need a full path location, just to separate privileges to different namespaces.

In Hive files are in hive_warehouse_path/database/table/partition and I'm looking for the same but in Hbase.

Can you help?

regards
Pawel

Edit: By the way, I've found an interesting slideshow about file structure in HBase: http://www.slideshare.net/enissoz/hbase-and-hdfs-understanding-filesystem-usage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under `${base.rootdir}/data` we have subdirectories related to namespaces and table names.

For example
Let's say we have this configuration in `hbase-site.xml`

```
 <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://hadoop:8020/apps/hbase</value>
 </property>
```

And we have namespace MyFirstNamespace with tables MyTable1, MyTable2 so the directory structure on hdfs will be:

```
/apps/hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable1
/apps/hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable2
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that you can use the hbase binary to find the current value of `hbase.rootdir`: 

`$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool hbase.rootdir`

Comment: Are you sure I was worth nothing in 2014 when this question was asked?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo, I meant to say: "It is worth *noting" -- I can no longer edit the comment.

Answer (score 5):

The configuration parameter `hbase.rootdir` in `hbase-site.xml` or `hbase-default.xml` tells HBase where to write in HDFS. You can find `hbase-site.xml` in the home directory by `ps aux | grep hbase.home.dir`.

From [the documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html):

> hbase.rootdir
>
> The directory shared by region servers and into which HBase persists. The URL should be 'fully-qualified' to include the
>   filesystem scheme. For example, to specify the HDFS directory '/hbase'
>   where the HDFS instance's namenode is running at namenode.example.org
>   on port 9000, set this value to:
>   hdfs://namenode.example.org:9000/hbase. By default, we write to
>   whatever ${hbase.tmp.dir} is set too -- usually /tmp -- so change this
>   configuration or else all data will be lost on machine restart.
>
> ```
> Default. ${hbase.tmp.dir}/hbase
> ```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This is 'root' path for hbase files, but are there any subdirectiries for namespaces/family names/ tables like in hive (warehouse/table/partition)?

Answer (score 1):

The Namespace for Hbase tables will be stored in the meta folder present at this location:

**/hbase/data/hbase/namespace/alphanumeric-number-folder-name/info/alpha-numeric-file-name**

This particular file will contain namespace.